# Movement of DNS server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I have been tasked with moving some server from one building to another, one of which is our main DNS server (Linux based OS on current server).

My question is what is best practice for performing such a task? should I setup a second DNS server at the new building on a new WAN IP and re-direct the traffic somehow until moving the current one across? ideally I would like a seamless transition.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a public DNS server (sounds like it is)? And you only have one setup anywhere?

Comment: Hi, this is a public DNS server yes and at present only the one.

Comment: How did you manage to register a public zone with only one DNS server in the first place? All TLDs I know require at least two servers with independant uplink for registration ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being that this is a single public DNS server, best practice would dictate that you first have a secondary DNS server hosting the records you are resolving on your primary server.  Once that is in place (giving 24 hours or so for worldwide propagation of the reference to the secondary server), then move the original server to the new location.

If you are concerned about a smooth transition, place an additional tertiary DNS server at the new site and then either move or decommission the old server.

Comment: Thanks for this Rob, seems to be the way forward on this.